# ASP.NET Core MVC - Can not find the simple way to display the data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Total beginner here. I am having problems displaying data from the database. The code below fetches the data from the row with "id" successfully.

```
Public IActionResult Item(int id)
{
    var ItemInDb = _context.Items.Find(id);

    if(ItemInDb == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(ItemInDb);
}
```

However, I can not find the simple way to display this data in corresponding view. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: You have to write the View, so your data becomes html.

Comment: The corresponding view is in place. I did figure out how to transfer the data as a while table into the view. However when I select one row with particular ID, I can not use "foreach" loop.

Comment: Can you share the structure of  `ItemInDb`?

Comment: As shown in the code above, var ItemInDb = _context.Items.Find(id). the row in corresponding table in the database has columns such as Id, ItemName, ItemPrice etc.